# WCF sending information to WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf

I want to send data from WCF to my desktop application while executing a service method.
The WCF service is hosted in windows service.

For example: In my service I am counting from 1 to 100 and when I am hitting 10,20,30 etc I want to set that value on my `textbox`.

Comment: I've just started WCF and i am totally noobie. Got the project that i have to finish in 2 weeks. My teacher is type of toxic and he dont want to help me.

Comment: `WCF` is not well suited for Real Time Communication. You could take a look at `SignalR` instead.

Comment: What about putting some type of listener to the Windows Service and host there some methods. Is that possible to comunicate that way windows service with desktop app? It dont have to be wcf, my teacher mentioned that when explaining a project idea (wrongly?). It must be the Windows Service and WPF application, but how to communicate these two in real time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be done using duplex channels services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Be careful however : this will not work if the server can't reach the client : for example if you are behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, gonna acquaint with that. Everything is running local so there shouldnt be problem with proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I've simpy passed that with get/set like below: (Maybe someone will search smthing similar in future)

```
    public class CallbackHandler : WCFService.IWCFServiceCallback
{
    public ListBox LtBox { get; set; }
    public void Message(string result)
    {
        LtBox.Items.Add(result);
    }
}

InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler() { LtBox=this.ltBox });
```

Where ltBox is my Listbox in desktop application.

Thanks all for help.